# bash grep regex from start of the string to variable

Tags: regex, bash, variables

I have a file with following strings and need to assign path to folder with digits into variable:

```
/tmp/gfh/000000004802803/blablabla/EngID_Consolidation.zip
/tmp/vcbn/000000005395825/blablabla/172_6578-DUMP_NOMServer.zip
/tmp/one3/435876dfhg/000000004017051/5.zip
/tmp/one3/dsfkgjh/dsjfhgfd/000000004617319/Sybase.zip
```

E.g. I need to assign in variable:
    /tmp/gfh/000000004802803/

Digits and path always different. As a first step I've assigned into variable folder with digits using regex:

```
zip_folder_name0=$(grep -E -o "/([0]{5}[0-9]{10})/" <<< $zip_path)
zip_folder_name=${zip_folder_name0#"/"}
zip_folder_name=${zip_folder_name%"/"}
echo $zip_folder_name
```

Which return 000000004802803
How to assign into another variable all path to folder from the root ?
I think it can be done by regex, from the start of the string to variable $zip_folder_name. Is this possile? Or maybe there is another way?

UPD1 Just forgot to mention, that after folder with digits can be another folder, e.g. /tmp/gfh/000000004802803/blablabla/EngID_Consolidation.zip And I need exactly /tmp/gfh/000000004802803/ into variable.

Comment: Update question with more details

Comment: are the digits always the 3rd field ? can there be other folders in the path with only digits ? (i.e. can you have `/tmp/gfh/ijk/012345/myzip.zip` or `/tmp/gfh/0123/4567/myzip.zip` ?)

Comment: There is always folder with 15 digits, but before and after can be folders with mixed digits and letters. No, there is no another folder with STRICTLY 15 digits in name, but can be folders with more or less then 15 digits. E.g. /tmp/gfh/000000004802803/123456/EngID_Consolidation.zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a script that will take an input parameter into `$IN_STR` and will spit out the string you require**

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_REGEX="[0-9]{15}"
IN_STR=$1

FIFTEEN_DIGIT_DIR_NAME=`echo $IN_STR | grep -E -o "$BASE_REGEX"`
FIFTEEN_DIGIT_DIR_CONTAINER=`echo $IN_STR | grep -Po ".*(?=$BASE_REGEX)"`

echo $FIFTEEN_DIGIT_DIR_CONTAINER$FIFTEEN_DIGIT_DIR_NAME
```

Outputs:

```
/tmp/gfh/00000000480280
```

Explanation: 
`grep -P` : Perl expression 
`-o` : only matching 
`.*` : Repeat everything 
`(?=)`: Query string  
`[0-9]`: any number 
`{15}` : 15 chars

**From comments, the requirement was like: Path up until the folder name containing exactly 15 digits, including the name of that folder itself.

Comment: Can you modify regex to amend variant with /tmp/gfh/000000004802803/12345 ?  (nested folder can contain only digits, but  it will not contain strictly 15 digits as parent folder).

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, you *don't* want the last `12345` to be included in the variable?

Comment: Yes, I want to cut off 12345, to have only /tmp/gfh/000000004802803/

Comment: oh, ok.. will change the answer, won't be an *amendment* though, sorry!

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for solution and sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Glad I could help out :) Oh and I wasn't pointing out a mistake in your English, if anything it was a problem with my own understanding while giving the first answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
while read line; do        
   dir=$(grep -oE .*/[0-9]+/ <<< $line|tr -d / )
   echo dir=$dir num=$num 
done < zips.txt 

> dir=/tmp/gfh/000000004802803/
> dir=/tmp/vcbn/000000005395825/
> dir=/tmp/one3/435876dfhg/000000004017051/
> dir=/tmp/one3/dsfkgjh/dsjfhgfd/000000004617319/
```

Comment: Might want `read -r`. And remember quotes around parameter expansions.

Comment: Just forgot to mention, that after folder with digits can be another folder, e.g. /tmp/gfh/000000004802803/blablabla/EngID_Consolidation.zip AndI need exactly /tmp/gfh/000000004802803/ into variable. Unfortunately, it's not possible with your answer.

Comment: When I have a nested folder after folder with 15 digits it returns dir=/tmp/gfh/000000004802803/blablabla/